# .NET call to service converting & to &AMP;

Tags: c#, .net, web-services

When we make a call from a .NET client to a service it is converting & to `&AMP;` (the html encoded version). Is there anyway to stop the conversion of the string value to `&AMP;` and have it keep the "&" when the service will pick it up.

Comment: Please show how you're making the call, where it's being converted etc.

Comment: There's a lot of missing context here...

Comment: Is this an ASMX web service?  WCF? REST web request?  Is this your own service or a 3rd party's?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better solution may be to decode the string on the server side:

```
String DecodedString = Server.UrlDecode(EncodedString);
```